# VB within Office Application: Is there a Sub Main()?

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio-2010

What is the relationship between Visual Studio IDE and the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications environment?

A colleague provided a VB script for manipulating Excel worksheets. Her script works well, and I'm using the task and her script to learn VB.

Instead of Visual Studio, her instructions have me open her Excel XLSM file and open the VB editor using Develop tab > Visual Basic button (or Alt-F11). There are three projects: ATPVBAEN.XLAM (The Analysis toolpack) which is password-locked, FUNCRES.XLAM (which contains two Sub, neither of which is named Main, and  no Modules), and a project from my colleagues XSLM file, which contains one Sub, which is also not named Main. Is there a Main in the locked file, or is a Main not needed as described in [Structure of a Visual Basic Program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/022td33t.aspx) ?

Comment: Perhaps related, I will post another question if not: How do I access a command line akin to the Command window for Studio described at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f177hahy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ?

Comment: VB.NET is quite different from VBScript or VBA.  The latter 2 are closer to VB6 (from 1998)

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks. I wanted to know what language is within Office 2010: VBScript or VBA. And wanted to know if there was a cnonical reference for that language. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx answers "VBA" and provides the docs.